# golang test setup for entire test run/package

Tags: testing, go

Is there a way to specify code to be run before all the tests in the current test run? Even when running tests across deeply nested directories? e.g.

```
a/
a/a_test.go
b/c/
b/c/c_test.go
d_test.go
```

I want to write some code that runs *once* before and *once* after all the tests in files `a_test.go`, `c_test.go`, `d_test.go` have run.

I know about [TestMain](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Main), which sorta does what I want if I needed to do this at the package level, but this doesn't run before/after all the tests in subdirectories/subpackages. I want something that's one level above `TestMain`.

I'm not limited to `go test`, so if there's a third-party test runner that would do this for go, that would be alright as well.

I'm looking for something akin to nosetests's `SetUpPackage` or pytest's session scoped fixtures.

Comment: `go test` only tests one package at a time. There is no such thing as "before/after all the tests in subdirectories/subpackages" in the context of `go test`.

Comment: thanks JimB. I'm slowly figuring that out. I'll edit the question to mention that I'm not limited to `go test` and welcome another test runner.

Comment: Anything else would be scripted around the invocation of `go test` on multiple packages -- most projects probably just use a makefile or shell script. There's no way to do this directly in Go, and recommendations for tools are OT.

Comment: And what if you use TestMain for each package calling a shared function that would work for package a, c and d?
It would reduce work to the minimum of calling 1 function by package. Is that too much?